# Running solve multiple timese

Tags: optimization, opl

I need to run a solve three times. Every time solve needs to have different input from different columns of a tuple. That is why I need to access the loop variable with in the OPL as a parameter and need to change that parameter with every loop. Please suggest how to do that in ODM OPL. 
(I am able to do it when running a standalone model with a physical .dat file by introducing a int in dat file and changing its values with each loop, but same is not possible when running through an ODM application).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a scripting `main()` function:

`.dat` file:

```
param = 0; // This value is actually never used
```

`.mod` file:

```
tuple T {
  int round1;
  int round2;
}
T t = <1, 2>;

int param = ...;

dvar float x;

minimize x;
subject to { x >= param; }

main {
  thisOplModel.generate();
  var def = thisOplModel.modelDefinition;
  var data = thisOplModel.dataElements;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    if (i == 0)
       data.param = thisOplModel.t.round1;
    else
       data.param = thisOplModel.t.round2;
    var opl = new IloOplModel(def, cplex);
    opl.addDataSource(data);
    opl.generate();
    cplex.solve();
    writeln("Round " + i + ": " + cplex.getObjValue() + ", " + data.param);
    opl.end();
  }
}
```

The scripting code modifies the data before creating a new model in each iteration. You have a more elaborate version of code like this in the `cutstock_main.mod` example that ships with CPLEX.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, it worked and served my purpose. Now I am facing other issue where I need to access the output generated by the "opl" model and use it int the ODM application to populate tables. When I am using thisOplModel, I am able to do it but not with "opl" model.

Comment: Since this is a different issue, can you please file a new question?

Answer (score 1):

What Daniel wrote works fine. If you do not want to have the non necessary .dat file you could write

sub.mod

```
tuple T {
  int round1;
  int round2;
}
T t = <1, 2>;

int param = ...;

dvar float x;

minimize x;
subject to { x >= param; }
```

and then in another model that will be the main one:

```
tuple T {
  int round1;
  int round2;
}
T t = <1, 2>;

main {
  thisOplModel.generate();
  var src = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var def=new IloOplModelDefinition(src);
  var data = new IloOplDataElements();;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    if (i == 0)
       data.param = thisOplModel.t.round1;
    else
       data.param = thisOplModel.t.round2;
    var opl = new IloOplModel(def, cplex);
    opl.addDataSource(data);
    opl.generate();
    cplex.solve();
    writeln("Round " + i + ": " + cplex.getObjValue() + ", " + data.param);
    opl.end();
  }
}
```

which will give

```
Round 0: 1, 1
Round 1: 2, 2
```

and

```
tuple T {
  int round1;
  int round2;
}
T t = <1, 2>;

int solutions[0..1];

main {
  thisOplModel.generate();
  var src = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var def=new IloOplModelDefinition(src);
  var data = new IloOplDataElements();;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    if (i == 0)
       data.param = thisOplModel.t.round1;
    else
       data.param = thisOplModel.t.round2;
    var opl = new IloOplModel(def, cplex);
    opl.addDataSource(data);
    opl.generate();
    cplex.solve();
    writeln("Round " + i + ": " + cplex.getObjValue() + ", " + data.param);
    thisOplModel.solutions[i]=opl.x.solutionValue;
    opl.end();
  }

  writeln(thisOplModel.solutions);
}
```

to address your next question about populating tables

which gives

```
Round 0: 1, 1
Round 1: 2, 2
 [1 2]
```